# how to position the <span> with background to the center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a slider seeker but cant seem to get it to the center of the div. I used `span` and kept the `background-image` as the seeker image. How do I set the position to the center. Is there any other good method to implement this.

```
   <div class="slider-seeker">
     <a href="#"><span class="position-image active"></span></a>
     <a href="#"><span class="position-image"></span></a>
     <a href="#"><span class="position-image"></span></a>
     <a href="#"><span class="position-image"></span></a>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j1bnbf3q/

Comment: do you want to align all span center in div?

Comment: Remove `float: left`.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

Create a wrapper div to contain the seeker buttons, and centralize the wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/pwLsb290/

## Solution 2

Apply `display: inline-block;` on the seeker buttons, and get rid of the `float` property. (The problem with this method is the whitespace associated with `inline-block` elements.)
http://jsfiddle.net/26dk1zeL/

Answer (score 0):

Used to  this css add your `.position-image` `display:inline-block` property and **remove** `float: left;`  as like this

```
.position-image{
    /* float: left; */  // remove this
    display: inline-block;  // add this
    vertical-align: top;   // add this 
}
```

=========== 
2nd option is

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j1bnbf3q/3/)**
used to this

```
.slider-seeker > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1bnbf3q/4/)

CSS:

```
.slider-seeker a{
 margin:0px auto;
}
.position-image {
 display:inline-table;
}
```